# VBA: passing a parameter to represent the number of columns to be added to combobox

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-access-2013

I am working on MS Access 2013/ VBA. function that initializes all the combo-boxes that are on a form. This function is called in the Load event of the form.

I am adding an initialize function for each of the combo boxes on the form, and this is very redundant, no mentioning that there are over 35+ combo-boxes on the form and the multiple tabs that the form also has.

My ideal is to have only one initialize function, and call it still from the load event, perhaps multiple times, but passing the necessary parameters to process each individual combo-box.

What I have right now (each call is calling a function that does basically the same):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Call InitializePriceCategory
    Call InitializePublisher
    Call InitializeAutoSearch
    Call InitializeConsultingFee
    Call InitializePermissionCode    

    On Error GoTo errhandler

eofit:

    Exit Sub

errhandler:

    z = ErrorFunction(Err, Err.Description, Erl, "Form_Load")

    Err = 0

    Select Case z
        Case 0: Resume Next
        Case 1: GoTo eofit
    End Select
End Sub
```

The only thing that changes for each function, is the select query that gets executed, the combo-box, and the number of columns that each specific combo-box needs to show.

Example of the function InitializePriceCategory:

```
Public Function InitializePriceCategory()

    Dim ADOCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADORS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim avarRecords As Variant
    Dim avarTransposedArray As Variant
    Dim avarOriginalArray As Variant
    Dim intRecord As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT" & _
             "  [Category]" & _
             ", [ProductDescription]" & _
             ", [BasePrice]" & _
             ", [AdditionalPrintPrice]" & _
             ", [MinimumPurchaseAmount]" & _
             ", [isChoral]" & _
             ", [isScoringBasedMinAmount]" & _
             ", [isTierBased] " & _
             "FROM [dbo].[z_PriceCategories] " & _
             "ORDER BY [Category]"

    Set ADOCon = New ADODB.Connection
    With ADOCon
        .ConnectionString = GetConnectionString("Conn")
        .Open
    End With

    Set ADORS = New ADODB.Recordset
    With ADORS
        .ActiveConnection = ADOCon
        .Open strSQL, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        avarRecords = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
    End With

    For intRecord = 0 To UBound(avarRecords, 2)

        ' Check for commas within the string on column 1 (description),
        ' otherwise the value gets truncated
        If InStr(avarRecords(1, intRecord), ",") > 0 Then
            avarRecords(1, intRecord) = """" & avarRecords(1, intRecord) & """"
        End If

        PriceCategory.AddItem (avarRecords(0, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(1, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(2, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(3, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(4, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(5, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(6, intRecord) & ";" & _
                               avarRecords(7, intRecord))

    Next intRecord
eofit:

    On Error Resume Next

    ADOCon.Close: Set ADOCon = Nothing
    ADORS.Close: Set ADORS = Nothing

    Exit Function

errhandler:

    z = ErrorFunction(Err, Err.Description, Erl, "InitializePriceCategory", , True)

    Err = 0

    Select Case z
        Case 0: Resume Next
        Case 1: GoTo eofit
    End Select

End Function
```

The biggest difference and most challenging for me to figure out how to work out, among each of the initialize functions so that I can have only one initialize function, is the number of columns.

My goal is to have something simple on the form load code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    Call InitializeCombo(Me.PriceCategory, "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8 FROM PriceCategory ", 8, ",")
    Call InitializeCombo(Me.PublisherName, "SELECT col1, col2 FROM Publishers ", 2, """")

eofit:

    Exit Sub

errhandler:

    z = ErrorFunction(Err, Err.Description, Erl, "Form_Load")

    Err = 0

    Select Case z
        Case 0: Resume Next
        Case 1: GoTo eofit
    End Select
End Sub
```

And then the InitializeCombo function code to be (incomplete idea):

```
Public Function InitializeCombo(pCombo As ComboBox, pQuery As String, pCols As Integer, Optional pSpecialCharacter As String)

    Dim ADOCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADORS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim avarRecords As Variant
    Dim avarTransposedArray As Variant
    Dim avarOriginalArray As Variant
    Dim intRecord As Integer    

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    Set ADOCon = New ADODB.Connection
    With ADOCon
        .ConnectionString = GetConnectionString("Conn")
        .Open
    End With   

    Set ADORS = New ADODB.Recordset
    With ADORS
        .ActiveConnection = ADOCon
        .Open pQuery, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        avarRecords = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
    End With

    ' ON THIS PART I AM NOT SURE HOW TO STILL BE ABLE TO DO THE SPECIAL CHARACTER CHECK 
    If InStr(avarRecords(1, intRecord), """") > 0 Then
        avarRecords(1, intRecord) = "'" & avarRecords(1, intRecord) & "'"
    End If

    For intRecord = 0 To UBound(avarRecords, 2)

        ' ON THIS PART, I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO INSTRUCT/ LOOP TO USE THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS PARAMETER 
        ' AND ADD THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS NEEDED; WHETHER ONE COMBO-BOX NEEDS 8 AND THE NEXT ONE ONLY NEEDS 2.
        pCombo.AddItem (avarRecords(0, intRecord) & ";" & _
                        avarRecords(1, intRecord) & ";")

    Next intRecord

eofit:

    On Error Resume Next

    ADOCon.Close: Set ADOCon = Nothing
    ADORS.Close: Set ADORS = Nothing

    Exit Function

errhandler:

    z = ErrorFunction(Err, Err.Description, Erl, "InitializeCombo", , True)
    Err = 0
    Select Case z
        Case 0: Resume Next
        Case 1: GoTo eofit
    End Select

End Function
```

I am thinking that what I need is to add another loop inside the first for loop that iterates through the records array, but I am not sure how to add this part.

I hope I can get some help on this issue as I think that I am close to get it right, I just ran into a roadblock I have not been able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your string in a variable that then you pass to the `AddItem()` function. Start with empty string `""` and then in the loop, add to the previous value. Use the counter as your index for the `avarRecords()` function:

```
Dim c As Integer
Dim s As String

For intRecord = 0 To UBound(avarRecords, 2)
    s = ""
    For c = 0 To pCols
        s = s & avarRecords(c, intRecord) & ";"
    Next c

    pCombo.AddItem (s)
Next intRecord
```